# Xamarin.Forms on Windows not loading styles from App.Xaml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have a Xamarin based app targeting iOS, Android, and Windows (not WinPhone but Windows 8.1 as a desktop app for now).

The app utilizes a few PCL's for the vast majority of all views and view models and reusable functionality.  The three platform specific projects have very little custom code and, when necessary, inject in custom platform specific services.  One of the PCL's also has an App.Xaml that provides the basic styles for the overall app.

The iOS and Android apps load this App.Xaml fine and honor all styles.  The Windows implementation of Xamarin.Forms does not appear to load or honor the styles in the same way and our core UI appears blank.

This isn't an issue of the styles just "don't look right" on Windows compared to the other platform but more an issue of everything is invisible.  We can click buttons and move around if we know where they would be in the overall UI but we don't see them.  Not even an outline.

Not sure what other implementation info I can provide but I'm wondering if anyone else has had issues with Xamarin.Forms on windows and styles?

Comment: That's rather strange issue! What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using? Could you add the code snippet to your question? It will be easier to debug